# dojo1.8 - Need on.pausable(fire, 'change', function()) to trigger select toggleDropdown and focus methods

Tags: dojo

Hi I have a problem and the error stated:-  "Error: Target must be an event emitter."
If there is a change in fire variable and selectHandler is resumed, shouldn't the methods be triggered - toggleDropDown and focus?

Here's my code below:-

```
var fire = false;
var toggle1, toggle2 = true;

var select = new Select
({
    store:storeA
}, 'node_Select');
select.startup();
fire = true;

var switchStore = new button 
({
    onClick: function()
    {if (toggle1)
        {
           select.setStore(storeB);
           toggle1 = false;
        }
    else
        {
           select.setStore(storeA);
           toggle1 = true;
        }
    fire = true;
    }
}, 'node_switchStore');
switchStore.startup();

var selectHandler = on.pausable(fire, 'change' function()
{
    if(fire)
        {
             select.toggleDropDown();
             select.focus();
             fire=false;
        }
})

var switchPause = new button
({
    onClick: function()
   {if (toggle2)
        {
           selectHandler.resume();
           toggle2 = false;
        }
    else
        {
           selectHandler.pause();
           toggle2 = true;
        }
    }
}, 'node_switchPause');
switchPause.startup();
```

What is event emitter? Only input change, button and DOM elements' events?
It seems that the fire variable is not event emitter, isn't it?
Please advise
Clement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with this line:

```
var selectHandler = on.pausable(fire, 'change' function()
```

You're trying to listen to one of javascripts primitive types, Boolean. In order for "dojo/on" to work, it has to listen to something that can fire off events. From what I'm seeing in your code sample, what you probably need is a function that handles the changing of the "fire" variable. How about something like this:

```
var openFire = function() {
    select.toggleDropDown();
    select.focus();
    fire = false;
}
```

now instead of setting

```
fire=true;
```

you can just call

```
openFire();
```

Comment: @ Richard, after changes...                                                                                                var fire = true;
var openFire = new function() {
    select.toggleDropDown();
    select.focus();
    fire = false; };                                                                        

var selectHandler = on.pausable(fire, 'change', function()
    {console.debug('after resumed');
    openFire();                              
         }); 
Still the error is reported: Target must be an event emitter

Comment: The open fire method is meant to replace the event handler. In any part of your code before where you wanted to set "fire=true", (like in your original post under the switchStore button), then you would replace it with the function openFire().